Cohomology of number fields, Theorem (8.7.9), $Ш^1(G_S,A)\to H^1(G_S,A)\to \prod_{p\in S} H^1(k_p,A)\to \hat{H^1(G_S,A')}$
I'm reading a book 'Cohomology of number fields' Second edition by J.Neukirhi A.Schmidt, K.Winberg.
In the page 511, theorem (8.7.9), there appears suddenly.
$Ш^1(G_S,A)\to H^1(G_S,A)\to \prod_{p\in S} H^1(k_p,A)\to \hat{H^1(G_S,A')}$.
The exact sequence in the front row probably comes from the Poitou-Tate exact sequence, but where was this exact sequence mentioned before? I can construct the surjection at the right end, but I think the main difficulty lies in proving the exactness at the local terms. I would appreciate any guidance.

The exactness of the first map is from the definition of the Tate-Shafarevich group as the kernel of the second map, and the other terms are from the Poitou-Tate long exact sequence itself (first shown in 8.6.10). And the map at the right end should not generally be surjective again from Poitou-Tate.

@Victor Lu Thank you very much. In this case, $S$ can be whole places of $K$, and in that case, is $G_S=G_K$ where $G_K$ is absolute Galois group of $K$ ?

If by "whole places" you mean all places then yes.
